# How to get a specific entry from a message | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a DC Bot that will accept registrations for an upcoming event, in order to do so a user needs to send a message in this format:

> Team Name:-
> Player 1-
> Player 2-
> Player 3-
> Player 4-

But what I want to extract from their message is only what they entered their Team's name. I have never done something like that before so if you can refer me to a similar code or docs then it would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy) to get the members list.

Invoke it like this `get_name @member1 @member2 Long team name`

```py
@bot.command()
async def get_team(ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *, Teamname: str):
    print(f"Team Leader: {ctx.author}")
    print(members)
    print(Teamname)
    if len(members) != 4:
        return await ctx.send("members must be 4)

    # code here
```